# Why is my url being modified with my setup?

Tags: alamofire

I have a tt-rss server I host behind a Trafik instance. The host is something like ttrss.example.com and I access it on the web like https://ttrss.example.com. It works just fine anywhere on the internet.

When I try to make a request like

```swift
AF
  .request(
    "\(url)/api",
    method: .post,
    parameters: ["user": user, "password": password],
    encoding: JSONEncoding.default
  )
  .responseDecodable(of: SessionResponseModel.self) { response in
    debugPrint("Response: \(response)")
  }
```

I get an error like

```
2022-09-29 21:24:36.652181-0400 ttc[89065:7539083] Task <808A492A-D131-448F-ADFD-4EE7158251D9>.<2> finished with error [-1022] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://ttrss.example.com:8889/api/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://ttrss.example.com:8889/api/, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <808A492A-D131-448F-ADFD-4EE7158251D9>.<2>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <808A492A-D131-448F-ADFD-4EE7158251D9>.<2>, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002b39e60 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1022 "(null)"}}
```

As you can see somewhere along the line Alamofire modified my url. Incidentally `8889` is the port my tt-rss server is running at behind Traefik.

My question is: why is Alamofire not just using the url I provide and like... Further resolving the url, but only partially?

I don't think this is an issue with neither tt-rss nor Traefik because both of those things are working just fine on every other part of the internet. There could be some config I am missing in Trafik that Alamofire needs, but beyond that I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Edit: I no longer thing this is Alamofire doing this. I believe it's Swift or iOS that's resolving the URL improperly (according to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error, this is an [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preventing_insecure_network_connections) error, meaning the system wasn't able to securely connect based on the default ATS rules. In your case it's because you're not using `https` at all. You either need to connect using `https`, or if you can't, enable insecure connections for that domain using the methods indicated in Apple's documentation.

Comment: Ok, after some further investigation, I realized that my setup is actually redirecting to the internal insecure url. The external url has a perfectly good certificate on it though. Is there a way to successfully handle this request in some way? I may need to tinker with my server but I know that my server works with _other_ iOS apps, so I am definitely missing something here